# How to get floatingSubviews in NSScrollView to use AutoLayout instead of Springs & Struts

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, autolayout, nsscrollview

I have added a subView to a custom `NSScrollView` using the `addFloatingSubview` method in the NSScrollView class.

While both the custom `NSScrollView` and custom `NSView` that I want to make floating have opted into AutoLayout explicitly, adding constraints on my custom view make it conflict with constraints that appear to be auto-generated by adding the floating subview in this manner.

It seems that I can set the width of the view and the leading constraint using AutoLayout but as soon as I try to add a trailing constraint, the conflict arises.

Further, it seems from the error message that an internal intermediate subView of `NSScrollView` has been created called `_NSScrollViewFloatingSubviewsContainerView` that is generating an `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` that is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Set the translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints to NO on the new views.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: I have stated above that I have already **explicitly** opted into AutoLayout - so I have already done as you have suggested.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your problem statement but if you're being told that an AutoResizingMaskLayout constraint is being created (a capture/screenshot of the conflicting constraints might also help provide clarity), some view in the hierarchy is still translating, right?

Comment: It's not one of my custom classes that is generating AutoResizingMaskLayout constraints but the internal (to Apple/Cocoa) class named _NSScrollViewFloatingSubviewsContainerView that is generating them.

Comment: Just to be clear, opting into Auto Layout (via the *Use Auto Layout* checkbox in the *File Insepector*) is **not** the same as setting the autoresizing mask to ``false``. In interface Builder, this option - *Translates Mask Into Constraints* - will appear in the *Attributes Inspector* if your view has no superview (i.e. is a free-standing object on the canvas). It is set to ``true`` by default, which means you will get system generated constraints. You need to make sure it is set to ``false``.